# Removing spaces between an apostrophe and letters in R

Tags: r, gsub

can someone help me remove spaces between a letter and an apostrophe in r? In other words; given an expression like: "don' t" I want a function that will
transform it to: "don't".

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
test <- c("don' t")
gsub("' ", "'", test)
```

in this very special case. but I guess you want some more general solution for longer strings?

Comment: why not just `gsub("' ", "'", test)`?

Comment: Simple and effective. It would work for even longer strings. For example if it were a sentence like: test<- c(" I didn 't like this at all. It 's terrible) then gsub(" '","'",tset) would work.. can you think of a case where it would fail?